# Prove that any Mersenne number is not a strong pseudoprimes to the base $3$?

Tags: number-theory, pseudoprimes

How do I prove the following Argument:

No Mersenne Number is a Strong Pseudoprime to base $3$.

Can anyone build on from this or re-prove my argument:

Start by eliminating composite exponents $p$ of $2^p-1$, so then only prime exponents are left. If $2^p-1$ is composite with $p$ prime, then every prime divisor $q$ of $2^p-1$ has the form $2kp+1$. If the divisor $q$ of $2^p-1$ does not divide $3^p-1$, then $2^p-1$ is not a strong pseudoprime base $3$. Do this for all divisors $q$ of $2^p-1$. What next?

Comment: $2^p-1$ prime $\implies 3^{2^p-1} \equiv 3 \bmod 2^p-1$. But since we use the [Lucas Lehmer test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) (which is very close to, but slightly more complicated) than the $3^{2^p-1} \equiv 3 \bmod 2^p-1$ test, if means that the converse is not true or not proven.

Comment: The Lucas-Lehmer test is instead that $(2+\sqrt3)^{2^{p-1}} \equiv -1 \bmod 2^p-1$. if it is then with $q$ the smallest prime factor of $2^p-1$ : $\text{order}_{\bmod q}(2+\sqrt{3}) = 2^p$ contradicting that the multiplicative group $a+b\sqrt{3} \bmod q$ has $q^2 \le 2^p -1$ elements